# Getting error in If condition if I use 'AND'

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make an if condition that checks a couple of things using 'And', and I get an error everytime

This is my if condition:

```
If rs.Fields("NM").Value = dictNM.Key[0] And rs.Fields("NODE_CD") = dictCD.Key[0] And rs.Fields("DT") = dictDT.Key[i] Then
```

Error:

```
Compile Error: Expected Then or GoTo
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the [] that are the problem.  It needs to be () in VB(A).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473840/how-can-i-seek-key-of-dictionary-by-index-value

Answer (score 0):

Try using () in each condition

And wich lenguage is exactly ? Looks like VB, but it may be another

Comment: Chuck, usually the language is given among the tags -- look at the blue boxes below the question. In this case, it is VBA in MS Excel.

Comment: @Jay (not sure the other ping reaches you) Please see the answer by jaykumar patel and my comment there.