# How can I seek key of dictionary by index value?

Tags: vb.net, excel

How can I get the key of a dictionary by passing the index value?

I'm trying:

```
If rs.Fields("NM").Value = dictNM.key(0)
```

that is, I want it to compare to the first key in the dictionary

but I get the error

```
Compile error: Invalid use of property
```

I tried googling, but to no avail. I'm hoping this is even possible.

Comment: It's fairly clear from the error message that `dictNM` is not a regular .NET Dictionary.  What it might be is unguessable but required to properly answer the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to use the Keys property:

```
dictNM.Keys(0)
```

Edit:
One thing to keep in mind is that the order of the keys is unspecified, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk.aspx)

Comment: @RajatJain - Can you explain what is not working? If you are using a `Dictionary` it will have a `Keys` property which you can use to retrieve an item at a specific index, but in general that is not the way to use a dictionary. In general you use a dictionary so that you can store and retrieve items using a specific key.

Answer (score 5):

Dictionary.ElementAt(index) works for me.  It returns the Key/Value pair at the specified index.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Pulling in LINQ and using `ElementAt(...)` is the best way to handle this, IMO.